# How to mathematically especify the number which causes a function to be maximum?

Tags: functions, notation

I have a function $f(x)$ and I evaluate it with five numbers, $x=1,2,3,4,5$.
Then I take the value which causes the function $f(x)$ to be maximum and use it to calculate a variable I want, for example:
$$R = \frac{(a + b + x_{max})}{3} $$

How do I write this in a correct mathematical notation?

I thought of something like:
$$R = \frac{(a + b + y)}{3} $$
where
$$y = argmax(f(x)) $$
for
$$x∈{1,2,3,4,5} $$

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can write $y=\arg\max(f(x))$ to avoid ambiguity with $x$.

Comment: Which value is chosen if the maximum value appears more than once ?

Comment: @Jamāl, thanks for the comment. I have corrected this ambiguity problem.